# Bayes-consistent cost-sensitive classification

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, online-learning

In cost-sensitive classification,
we have a confusion (or cost) matrix
$C$, where $C(i,j)$ is the cost incurred
for predicting label $i$ when nature
specifies $j$. The costs are non-negative,
but no other restriction (such as symmetry) need be imposed. In the classic setting
(PAC and its multiclass generalization),
$C(i,j)=1[i\neq j]$.

The notion of Bayes-consistency carries
over naturally to the cost-sensitive setting. For any joint distribution
$P$
over the instances
$\mathcal{X}$
and labels
$\mathcal{Y}$,
we define the risk of a predictor
$f:\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}$
as
$$
R(f)=
\mathbb{E}_{(X,Y)\sim P}
C(f(X),Y).
$$
Letting $f^*$ be a minimizer of
$R(\cdot)$ over all measurable $f$,
we define the Bayes-optimal risk as
$R^*:=R(f^*)$.

Question: What is known about Bayes-consistent classification in the cost-sensitive setting? For example,
when $\mathcal{X}$ is a metric space
and $C(i,j)=1[i\neq j]$, various nearest-neighbor methods are known to be strongly Bayes-consistent. Is anything known about other cost matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but people have studied consistency of *surrogate risk minimization*. There, we define a surrogate loss function $L$ and a link $\psi$. We first minimize surrogate loss on our dataset, yielding some surrogate hypothesis $h$. Then we define $f(x) = \psi(h(x))$. This procedure is roughly consistent if, as data $\to \infty$, we have $f \to f^*$.

The question is, given e.g. $C$, what are some nice, consistent surrogate losses? Example: for binary $0-1$ loss, one can use hinge loss or logistic loss as a surrogate, and one can show this is consistent as long as the hypothesis class is rich enough.

Tewari and Bartlett (2007) study multiclass classification, but I think not cost-sensitive, and relate consistency to *calibration*. A more recent work is Agarwal and Agarwal (2015), which has some more references.

[1] Tewari, Bartlett. *On the Consistency of Multiclass Classification Methods.* JMLR 2007. https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/tewari07a/tewari07a.pdf

[2] A. Agarwal, S. Agarwal. *On consistent surrogate risk minimization and property elicitation.* COLT 2015. http://proceedings.mlr.press/v40/Agarwal15.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @usul! I should read these carefully, but they all deal with the case where the labels are "atomic" -- i.e., have no cost/metric structure?

Comment: @Aryeh I think that's correct for Tewari and Bartlett, but Agarwal and Agarwal consider a general (finite-dimensional) "loss matrix" where predicting $t$ when the true label is $y$ gives loss $L(y,t)$.

Comment: Great -- I'll accept it, and hopefully others will add further references that come up.